# Flutter: CheckboxListTile remove default padding

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm looking to remove this padding around my row of CheckboxListTiles, but haven't found any information on how to do this without making my own version of a checkbox.

[image]

Is there any way to (using the CheckboxListTile):

1. Remove the (blue) left and right padding of the CheckboxListTile
2. Increase the width of the text area (I've tried sizedbox, containers, etc with no luck)

Comment: None of the answers work for the dumb vertical padding.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**UPDATE**: There is no need to use `ListTitleTheme` anymore. **`contentPadding`** is now one of `CheckboxListTile`'s properties. We can now remove the default `padding` like this:

```
CheckboxListTile(
 contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
)
```

Comment: Only removes the horizontal padding.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar - vertical padding is not yet adjustable; see [CheckboxListTile leading icon vertical position parameter alignment is needed #27932](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27932)

Comment: Simple and elegant. Huge thx!

Answer (score 11):

the right way to remove gap between *checkbox and title* is to use **horizontalTitleGap**

```
ListTileTheme(
   horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
  child: CheckboxListTile(
    secondary: const Icon(Icons.drive_eta),
    title: Text("Your message"),
    onChanged: (bool value) {},
    value: true,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 9):

Try using the following code:

```
ListTileTheme(
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
  child: CheckboxListTile(
    secondary: const Icon(Icons.drive_eta),
    title: Text("Your message"),
    onChanged: (bool value) {},
    value: true,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
ListTileTheme(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
```

then

```
 ListTileTheme(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            child: CheckboxListTile(
              activeColor: CustomColors.purple,
              title: Text("title text"),
              value: true,
              onChanged: (newValue) {},
              controlAffinity:
                  ListTileControlAffinity.leading, //  <-- leading Checkbox
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
```

is the good option

Answer (score 2):

```
ListTileTheme(
    horizontalTitleGap: 0,
    child: CheckboxListTile(
      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
      title: Text(
        title,
        style: kRegularFontStyle.copyWith(
          fontSize: 16.0.sp,
          color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.color,
        ),
      ),
      value: isChecked,
      onChanged: onChanged,
      activeColor: kStructuralBlue500,
      checkColor: kWhiteColor,
      checkboxShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0.r)),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 2):

In CheckboxListTile, use below property when EdgeInsets.zero not making any difference.

```
visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: -3, vertical: -4),
```

Density values must be 0 or negative.

Answer (score 2):

Use this one instead of using CheckBoxListTitle

```
    Row(
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
children: [
  Checkbox(
    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
    value: firstvalue,
    onChanged: (bool? newValue){
      //Do Something When Value Changes to True Or False
      setState(() {
          this.firstvalue = newValue!;
      });
    },
  ),

  Text('Enable Touch ID'),
])
```

Comment: Suggesting a completely different solution instead of solving the specific issue of removing default padding, may not help the community.

Answer (score -2):

There are couple ways:

1. Create a stack and place the checkboxes with `Positioned` widget (basically your own variation of CheckboxListTile)
2. Copy the flutter checkbox widget code into your own file
   (`custom_checkbox.dart`), find the part where they added the padding/ margin, set it to 0. 3)
3. Try out other checkbox packages existing
   on pub.dev like flare_checkbox or circular_chekbox.

All of those approaches have its advantages and disadvantages as you can imagine.

**Edit**

I have created for you a custom checkbox list tile, where the padding is much smaller.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
            checkboxTile('Charger'),
            checkboxTile('Bag'),
            checkboxTile('Mouse'),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget checkboxTile(String title) {
    return Row(children: [
      Text(title),
      Checkbox(value: true, onChanged: (v) => null),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Make sure to convert `checkboxTile` into a stateless widget if you wanna use that implementation.

[click here to see custom checkbox list tile as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgWI0.jpg)

Comment: I'm hoping to not have to resort to re-making the checkboxes, so option 2 seems to be the best option, but I don't know where you would find that padding/margin info.

Comment: try to search in the source code of `CheckboxListTile` for `Padding` or `Margin`. Also try to search for `InkWell`, that sometimes has an internal padding.

If you find padding or margin set it to 0. If you find an InkWell replace it with a GestureDetector.